# Maximizing $11a+2b-ab$ for non-negative integers $a$ and $b$ less than $10$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Maximize $11a+2b-ab$ for non-negative integers $a$ and $b$ less than $10$

I solved this problem by factoring,

$$\max(11a+2b-ab)= \max((11-b)(a-2)+22)= (11\times7)+22=99$$

Although it is a fine and straightforward approach for solving this problem, I'm interested to see other approaches too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is linear in both variables, so the extrema is one of $ f(0, 0), f(0, 9), f(9, 0), f(9, 9)$.

Checking these 4 values, the maximum is $f(9, 0) = 99$.

Answer (score 2):

$$L:= \underbrace{a}_{\le 9}\cdot\underbrace{(11-b)}_{\ge 0}+2b \le 9\cdot(11-b)+2b=99-7\cdot\underbrace{b}_{\ge 0}\le 99$$